# Include Boost file gets file not found error

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to get boost running so that I can use a C library as an external library for my python program. But I keep getting the file not found error when including header files.

I'm following the tutorial on Boost's website: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/more/getting_started/windows.html

I've downloaded boost and extract it to my C disk. Added its directory (C:\Program Files\boost_1_76_0) to the include path in vscode using Microsoft C/C++ extension

However, when I tried to follow this example from the tutorial above:
(There were no python codes involved yet just C++)

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " " );
}
```

I get the error "fatal error: boost/lambda/lambda.hpp: No such file or directory
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>" even though the file exists.

Comment: Does including Python header files work? The difference between the way the two paths are specified seems obvious. That said, please don't use pictures on external, volatile sites in order to represent text. Include that inline here rather. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Python header files. I created a whole different project to test if I could use the library so everything up to now was written in C++. Also thank you for the edit suggestion.

Comment: I thought I had seen an entry amoung your settings which pointed to Python includes (which are for use with C and C++).

Comment: I just now realized that I mistakenly included the python library through the Microsoft C/C++ extension. I didn't do anything with it tho. I tried to make a small program to test if the import works correctly and it did, but I don't think it has to do with my C/python/include dir being included in includePath.

Comment: "the file exists" Which file? `boost/lambda/lambda.hpp` is a **relative path**, i.e. it only refers to an existing file when you are at a certain working directory. You need to explain what is the **absolute path** of the file, and why you think `#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>` should be looking at that absolute path.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I was talking about lambda.hpp file. So what I did was following the tutorial linked above (I believe the source is credible). I extracted to boost library to C:\ProgramFiles so that should make the absolute path be C:/ProgramFiles/boost/lambda/lambda.hpp. I tried using that absolute path instead of 'boost/lambda/lambda.hpp' but vscode prompted an error saying 'include error detected'. How do I properly declare my absolute path?